# Wordpress Query Attachments with ACF field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm trying to return all the images within the media library that have a custom field with the value of `True`.

For some reason nothing is being returned, this is what I have so far:

```
function showPainted() {
    $query_images_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'meta_key'      => 'show_on_painted_page',
        'meta_value'    => '1'
    );

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
        $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    }

    print_r($images);
}
add_shortcode( 'showPainted', 'showPainted' );
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: `print_r($query_images)` and check the results.

Answer (score 2):

Please change your query agrs as:

```
$query_images_args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            //'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'      => 'show_on_painted_page',
            'meta_value'    => true
        );

        $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked, it's still returning nothing.

Comment: Did you print this as `print_r($query_images)`?

Comment: Yea, ` [post_count] => 0`

Comment: check meta_key `show_on_painted_page` in database postmeta table that meta_value is 1 or true and then pass that value in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page'    => - 1,
    'meta_key'          => 'show_on_painted_page',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'show_on_painted_page',
            'value'     => 1,
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
    ),
);
```

Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for more informations.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't worked, it's still returning nothing.